# Android App orientation change restarts activity

Tags: android

I have an activity and it is getting restarted whenever orientation changes. I have written code to prevent activity restart upon change in orientation in the manifest file as given below:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.sample.appname.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

In the above code snippet **android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"** is supposed to do the work for me but the activity is still getting restarted. Please let me know how to correct it.

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason to, you should not try to prevent the activity from being recreated. Instead you should properly manage your activity state and save any necessary state in `onSaveInstanceState()`, then use the `Bundle` provided in `onCreate()` to restore state appropriately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually you shouldn't prevent the Activity to be restarted. It is neccessary to recreate the Activity after a rotation change for several reasons. One of it is that the layout has to be inflated to deal with the changed screen size and things like that (it's easy to imagine that the layout is totally different in portrait than it is in landscape mode).
However, there is a way you can tell the system that you deal with the screen changes by yourself. Therefore change the line in your manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

to

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

The activity won't be recreated then. You'll get a callback via the [`onConfigurationChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)) method so you can do something when the orientation has changed. If you don't want to do anything when the configuration has changed, just don't override the `onConfigurationMethod()` in your Activity. Read [this section in the Android Developers API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) for more information.

I got this from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5913370/5247502). There are two more approaches in the answer but I think the one I described above is the best in your case.

**EDIT:** Maybe you have to add `keyboard|keyboardHidden` to the `android:configChanges` attribute as well, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13149621/5247502)

---

**EDIT #2:** If you want to retrieve the current orientation of the device you can call

```
Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

which will return the constants `ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` or `ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`.

If you're interested in the exact rotation angle, use

```
int rotation =  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
```

and implement a differentiation with something like a switch case described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23930318/5247502).

And a third way to determine the device's rotation is `getRequestedOrientation()` which will return a constant defined in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#screenOrientation)

Comment: Can we somehow determine if the orientation has been changed inside onCreate event?

Comment: @MakeInIndia I've updated my answer, I hope this helps. Feel free to accept it if it helped you solving your problem

Answer (score 0):

android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" means whenever screen orientation will be changed a following method in Activity class will be called.

```
  @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) { body }
    }
```

This is nature of andorid that whenever screen orientation is changed whole lifecycle of activity runs again.

To save and restore some data. you can use following methods.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);

    outState.putString("key","value");
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    String s = savedInstanceState.getString("key");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Into

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

this should solve your problem, but it is not a efficient way, for a better option refer  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html